# can't link to app store review page

Tags: ios

i've tried to create a link to the app store from my app. I found a lot of posts telling me to do it like this:

```
 NSString* appID = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];\

 NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=%@", appID];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

When i click on the button linked to this code, i get redirected to the app store, but then a pop-up shows and tells me "can't connect to the app store"

What am i missing? is this method deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found what the problem  is :

```
NSString* appID = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
```

doesn't retrieve the app id; for that you must go to itunes connect